# sql server 2016, JSON_VALUE does not give right values

Tags: json, sql-server

I am using SQL server 2016 which supports JSON. I am trying to query JSON in question using JSON_VALUE keyword but I am not able to do so. can someone point out what could be the reason.

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(max) = (
SELECT
    FilesReadyForUpload AS FilesReadyForUpload
FROM [HB].[Heartbeats] with (nolock)
where DATEDIFF(ss, heartbeats.ReceivedAt, GETUTCDATE()) <= 3600
    and heartbeats.SystemName is not NULL
    and heartbeats.Router = 'xxxxxx'
)
select * from OPENJSON(@json)
>>>>
blackbox    0   2
camera      0   2
config      0   2
events      4   2
isi_printf  0   2
kinematic   0   2
tool_table  0   2

select * from OPENJSON(@json) where JSON_VALUE(@json,'$.value') >0
>>>> No Output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `WHERE` clause `JSON_VALUE(@json,'$.value')` is trying to retrieve a field named `value`, which according to your `OPENJSON` output does not exist, so the `WHERE` clause evaluates to false and returns no rows from `OPENJSON`.

If you're trying to return the fields whose value is greater than 0 you probably want to do the following:

```sql
declare @json nvarchar(max) =
N'{
  "blackbox": 0,
  "camera": 0,
  "config": 0,
  "events": 4,
  "isi_printf": 0,
  "kinematic": 0,
  "tool_table": 0
}';

select * from openjson(@json) where value > 0;
```

Which yields the result:

```
key     value  type
events  4      2
```